# Specification of Unicoins

Tags: support, unicoins

I am highly interested to know the specification of Unicoins.
mainly interested in the following:

- Algorithm
- Coins to be issued
- Block Time , etc

Comment: It's not even April 1st for another 8 hours here, and these questions are already boring the crap out of me. Guess I will visit meta again on April 2.

Comment: I'm more interested in Bolt Clock time.

Answer (score 30):

Yes.

Comment: How to turn it on? I don't see any Unicoins anywhere, just others reporting it... is this A/B testing?

Comment: difficulty to mine increasing crazily .. which hardware is best ? asic or gpus ?

Comment: @Vamsi - mouse.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes. The A stands for "April 1st where you're at", the B is for "Be patient, young padawan".

Comment: I believe it's an April Fool's prank, where changes are reflected in one's own profile only. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Which time zone are you in nowadays, balpha?

Comment: @Arjan UTC+2. I'm not seeing them either yet...

Comment: @n00bProgrammer it's absolutely serious. We never do April fools.

Comment: @balpha but as a dev you surely have a big red button "Activate Unicoins Now", right? ;)

Comment: @Sklivvz, absolutely. I can hear the Vulcans celebarting with cake,  kool-aid, and a screening of American Beauty. :P

Comment: @ShadowWizard you realize that we've been testing this for the past 6-8 weeks, right? :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz and poor telkitty was an innocent victim... or wasn't it coincidence? ;)

Comment: 99-unicoins for happy unicorn animations every time I vote.  I did want it, and it's awesome.  I hope this is forever.  As well, we need more unicornify avatars days, @balpha.

Answer (score 5):

### Algorithm

The language is Unicorn, and the complete source code is:

```
unicoin
```

### Coins to be issued

There will be no more than `unicorn` number of coins issued, though it is not guaranteed that all will be issued.

### Block Time , etc

The average block time is `unicorn` seconds per block.

Comment: Are those metric or imperial unicorns?